# Obtaining OAuth credentials for Google Drive API

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am trying to get access to some files on google drive via an application I am developing. Unfortunately I am having difficulties in obtaining the credentials. I have created an Google Service Account and the provided email-Address and private key should be ok.
However when calling the method `getDriveService()` from below, I am receiving the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.<init>(GoogleCredential.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.build(GoogleCredential.java:515)
```

Am I doing something obvious wrong here?

My code so far:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;

import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "VERY_LONG_ID@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = "/home/user/googledriveKey.p12";

public static Drive getDriveService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
            new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
        .build();
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
        .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
    return service;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation clearly shows how to obtain the credentials (this is what you already have):

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
   .setTransport(httpTransport)
   .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
   .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
   .setServiceAccountScopes(DriveScopes.DRIVE)
   .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
       new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
   .build();
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts

If you want to access data from google drive of an individual user you also need to call

```
   .setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#instantiate_a_drive_service_object

Comment: You're right. That documentation page was exactly what I was looking at and (embarassingly) it seems that at first I've simply missed the `setServiceAccountScopes` method-call. I'll delete my own answer and accept this one. Thank you